# How to disable creating hardlinks

Tags: python, tar, tarfile

Using python's tarfile module, is there a way to specify the equivalent of tar's Q option (note: Haiku specific)?

```
tar --help
  -Q, --replace-hardlinks    replace hardlinks with corresponding symlink when
                             extracting
```

Currently the code is essentially:

```cs
tarFile = tarfile.open(archiveFile, 'r')
members = None
if subdir:
    members = [
        member for member in tarFile.getmembers()
        if member.name.startswith(subdir)
    ]
tarFile.extractall(targetBaseDir, members)
tarFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can work around it by using the `islink()` method of the `TarInfo` objects returned by members. Something like the following:

```
tarFile = tarfile.open(archiveFile, 'r')
   for member in tarFile.getmembers():
        if member.islnk():
             # code for handling links
        else:
            tarFile.extract(targetBaseDir, member)
tarFile.close()
```